Adding source code of a nuget package to another solution
I have a Visual Studio 2022 / ASP.NET Core Web API project named Portal.API that consumes a NuGet package RefData.API from a private NuGet feed.
I also have a Visual Studio 2022 source code of that package RefData.API in a separate project/solution.
When I work on the project Portal.API, I want to be able to temporarily add the mentioned source code of the package RefData.API to the solution, so that I can work on changes in both the project and nuget package simultaneously.
How to do this in Visual Studio 2022?

Would it be helpful if you have a local NuGet gallery where you can publish releases locally?

Here is the source code for the RefData.API project I created myself and published to my private NuGet source:

I don't know your approximate project structure, but after my testing, you can refer to the following example steps to complete the operation of adding the source code of a nuget package for another solution:
1: Create a new ASP.NET Core Web API project in the new solution as you need.
2: In Solution Explorer, right-click the solution name and select Add > Existing Project….
3: Browse to the folder of the RefData.API project, select the .csproj file of the project, and click Open.
4: In Solution Explorer, right-click the project and select Add > Project Reference…. In the pop-up window, click Browse…, find and select the RefData.API.dll file of the RefData.API project, usually in the bin directory, and then click OK.
5: Right-click the Controllers folder and add a new API Controller - Empty file and use the following code (Class1 in the code is the class name in my nuget package, you can modify it according to the code in your nuget package):

6: After running, you can see that the corresponding results are successfully returned:

